# java dependency inject ambiguous overwrite

Tags: java, dependency-injection, resteasy, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi generator to generate `java-resteasy` server stub code template, my idea is that use the generator generate some interface that I will never modify, and I will implement that interface with my own code.

However, the generator already generated implementation class, I write my own implementation class which extends the generated one. So now there're two implementation classes, so CDI complains about the ambiguouty:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: Ambiguous dependencies for type openapidemo.gen.FruitsApiService and qualifiers [@Default]
```

is there any way to mark my own implementation class as first priority when CDI try to discover bean? so as to overwrite the one generated by openapi.

**edit:**

Per @Negi answer, `@Alternative` might be a way to indicate a class as low priority when CDI searching bean, however, in my case, I want to hide the generated code without modifying it since I will check it in my repo, and I expect the code generation is idempotent. So is there any way to annotate a class as "prioritize" with my own implementation class, as opposite to `@Alternative`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file named `.openapi-generator-ignore` and mention the files you would like not to generate.

https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/faq-extending/#how-do-i-skip-files-during-code-generation

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous because CDI searches for beans by type and your entity and the producer method return the same type.

Please add **@Alternative** annotation at bean level.

Comment: If I understand it correctly the Alternative annotation should be added to the one that I want to ignore, in my case, is the generated code. But I don't want to modify the generated code since I will check it in my repo, and I expect the code generation is idempotent. So is there any way to annotate a class as "prioritize", as opposed to alternative?